# How to fix a software bricked android smartphone?

Tags: unbricking

Two days ago i began to look after advantages and disadvantages of rooting a device, and i thought that rooting my phone would be helpfull. I rooted my phone succefully using vroot
and i had not any issue after rooting.
     After installing Chainfire 3d which is only for android 2.3(according to my actual knowledge), when i installed the driver asked by this program the phone rebooted and get stucked at the vendor logo and nothing happens after the logo appears on the screen.
My phone model is ALLview A5 Smiley.
     I do not have any backup at my disposition but i can access Recovery mode(vol up + power on).
Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: If you know/can find out how to flash the stock ROM, you can simply flash that and revert your system (not your data) back to stock (unrooted, unmodified, no ChainFire3D). I predict `fastboot` but I don't know your device.

Comment: It is an Allview A5 Smiley.

Comment: My brother has the same type of smartphone as me. There is a way to copy his firmware or to make backup of his system and copy into my sd card?Does this helps?

Comment: You'll likely be able to download the firmware online.

Comment: Seems to be a kind of hobby to install Chainfire 3D in order to get the device stuck: [See the other questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Chainfire+3d+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late, but yes, you should be able to get the disk images from your brother's phone and install them on yours.

Short steps:

1. Install TWRP recovery on both phones
2. Do a complete nandroid backup of your bother's phone
3. Restore it to your phone
   ...
   profit.

If more details are required for each step, leave a short comment.